# Immirzi parameter and it’s Critical values

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

Where does the critical values of the [Immirzi parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immirzi_parameter), i.e. log(2)/pi(3^1/2), etc. come from? Is there an equation that relates these values to the general immirzi parameter?

What is the dependence of the parameters on the assumption of spins other than spin-1/2 being negligible?